# Pulling in Dynamiclly Generated (not a static file) CSS in FF?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-3, dynamic-css

Is there any way of pulling in a CSS stylesheet into FireFox 2 or 3 that is not a static file?

Bellow is the code we are using to pull in a stylesheet dynamically generated by a CGI script.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cgi-bin/Xebra?ShowIt&s=LH4X6I2l4fSYwf4pky4k&shw=795430-0&path=customer/DEMO/demo1.css" type="text/css">
```

/cgi-bin/Xebra?ShowIt&s=LH4X6I2l4fSYwf4pky4k&shw=795430-0&path=customer/DEMO/demo1.css

**Note that the URL above that pulls in the CSS does not end with .css rather the parameters do.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the Content Type from the server the correct one for the file that is served up?

```
Content-type: text/css
```

Comment: To be clear, your headers should contain "Content-type: text/css"

Comment: I believe this to be the answer, I'm gonna let the guys try it out first before I select the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

why isn't this working?
Double check that the response header for the cgi script has

```
Content-Type: text/css
```

Answer (score 3):

The extension doesn't matter but you should make sure the content type is **"text/css"**.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing in the past - [a former employer's site](http://support.specorp.com) uses a link tag much like yours, and works fine in FF2 at least (I just checked it, though I tested it in FF when we added that link). If it's not working, I'd suspect it's something about the generated CSS file rather than the importing page. The consensus appears to be the Content-Type from the server may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your server procs (like the CGI) run first, don't they? Seems to me that that link tag will only pull in a file that exists already.

So what I'd do is put a server tag (my lang's ASP/ASP.Net, but you could use PHP or anything, really) in the href.

Like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css href="<% =getStylesheetPath() %>" media="all">
```

Give that a shot.